# What is the standard screen resolution we should design for in a Mac App Store application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, mac-app-store, screen-size

On the iPhone, we design applications around a standard screen size of 320x480.  Is there a standard screen size we should use for developing Mac applications, specifically ones targeted to the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't.** Desktop computers don't have a fixed size like phones do. Users could have a screen (or two or six) with a resolution [anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_display_resolutions) from 800x600 to 3200x2400 or more.

Instead, design your application to be dynamically resizable. Allow the user to resize windows by dragging their corners to make them as large as they want. Ensure that the layout of elements is fluid, and that they move/resize accordingly as their parent window is resized.

Whatever you do, *do not* try and lock your users into a particular resolution or window size. They will resent it, and your app will not be very successful. You need to abandon the iPhone model when developing Macintosh applications. There are some similarities, but also lots of important differences.

Examine the other applications on your computer, and see how they behave. Good examples are the applications Apple bundles with new Macs, like iTunes, iPhoto, TextEdit, Pages, and Keynote, among others. Certain third-party companies also design award-winning software applications, like [Panic's Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/), [Fetch](http://fetchsoftworks.com/), and even [Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products). Hard to go wrong by following their example.

Comment: thanks cody...liked the way u answered..appreciate it...very informative for me.

Comment: I'm interested in this magical screen that has more resolution than 3200x2400, since no display interface on a mac actually supports that.

Comment: (3840x2160 is the theoretical maximum supported by Displayport - or some variant on that many pixels - and no commercially available ramdac actually runs at a CVT high enough to support that)

Comment: @Nick: Option One: You could have multiple monitors treated as a single monitor by the display adapter. Option Two: You're taking that minute detail of the answer *far* too literally. Technical details like that are irrelevant, as they're very likely to be completely obsolete within a few months, if not a year. Screens continue to get larger, the average resolution continues to increase. This is sound software advice; I'm explicitly *not* telling him to count for an upper bound of 3200x2400 or even 3840x2160.

Answer (score 3):

For all modern macs, at least 1024x768 will be usable screen real estate (the actual screen will be larger, but you need to account for menu bars, 16:9, etc.).  Still, this is generally not a good question to ask - you should probably have dialogs that look good at 800x600 and scale larger at the very least - most people like to be able to arrange their windows to their preferences, and if you have a large minimum size that will be very annoying.

Comment: A too small size is also annoying on my 27" iMac at work with 2560x1440... a 320x480 window is barely visible here ;-)

Comment: was curious about the image resolution for mac app, how should desingers should work to create images for mac app.thanks for replying Nick

Comment: Clearly the rule should be "you're allowed to set a minimum, but it needs to be small...640x480 or 800x600 at the most...and you must allow your windows to resize properly to very large screen resolutions"